# Why Angular2 (click) event is not firing on a <div>?

Tags: angular

I found a strange behaviour with Angular2:

`(click)` isn't firing on this:

```html
<div (click)="test()">test</div>
```

But it works here:

```html
<div style="position: relative;" (click)="test()">test</div>
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Why there is a need to set position style in order for (click) to fire?

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on plunker?

Comment: Please reproduce it. I'm pretty sure that problem is in your markup and styles

Comment: where is your **component.ts** module declarations and so on. with one line of HTML nothing can be helped.

Comment: nowadays angular use stopropagation by default, and remember to put a id o key on the element selected

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Your code snippet looks all good!

The issue is in your CSS styles. Your `<div>` probably either inherits a different `position` value or simply - **goes behind another element which element blocks your `<div>` (does not allow it to be clicked)**.

By changing the position to `relative` it works, most probably because this position enables `z-index` and moves your `<div>` on top to the other element that's blocking it.

This should be enough for you to figure it out. But if you want more detailed answer - please share your CSS too.

Comment: Thanks. It is an issue with the css. I am using Angular-cli, on a fresh project all works fine. When I add bootstrap4 I see this behavior probably due to bootstrap's default css.

Comment: I am getting the same issue with Angular 4 and Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same issue, and the problem was that I named an HTML element and the method the same.

It was such:

mycomponent.html

```html
<div #doSomething>
</div>

<div (click)="doSomething();">
</div>
```

mycomponent.ts

```js
doSomething() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the similar issue mostly time on Iphone. basically the pointer-event causing the stuck on the components. So I just applied the below fix at all the events where i applied the (click) property on the tag.

```
    a,
    div,
    ion-item,
    .item-md,
    .item-ios,
    .segment-button,
    .select-md
    .select-ios,
    .button-ios,
    .button-md,
    .searchbar-md,
    .searchbar-ios {
        pointer-events: auto !important;
    }
```

Now it is working fine in both Android and IOS platform.

Answer (score 1):

I add a tag inside div tag

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of curriculumArray">
    <a (click)="goToDetail(item.curriculumId)">
    <p class="p-title">{{ item.curriculumName }}</p>
    <p class="p-description">{{ item.description }}</p>
    <div class="icon-button">
      <img
        class="delete"
        title="Xóa chương trình"
        src="../../../assets/icon/delete_icon.png"
        alt="delete button"
      />
      <img
        class="edit"
        title="Chỉnh sửa chương trình"
        src="../../../assets/icon/edit_icon.png"
        alt="edit button"
      />
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div (click)="myFunction()"> 
<my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

^ this worked for me