# click function not triggered for moving div

Tags: angular

I have a `div` that is moving because I am changing its position each 20 ms. But when I click on that div, the function associate with is not working. I wonder if that is related to the div position being changed very quickly.

```html
<div class="box-position" 
  [style.top.px]="box.top" 
  [style.left.px]="box.left"
  (click)="onTarget(box)"></div>
```

```js
ngOnit(){
  //the observable events occurs each 20ms
  this.service.subscribe(data => this.box = data)
}

onTarget(box){
  console.log("clicked")
}
```

Here is the [live code](https://moving-div.stackblitz.io)

Comment: what does your service return ?

Comment: This could be that because the div is moving, it's actually triggering a drang and drop event. Try binding to that, see what happens

Comment: @PardeepJain, it returns a json like this: `{top: 320, left: 450}` for instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537122/why-angular2-click-event-is-not-firing-on-a-div

Comment: @PranayRana, when my observable stops emitting value (box no longer mooves), I am able to get the output of the function upon clicking on the box , which indicates that it is not related to the styling of the box

Comment: can you set z-index of it higher then other and also check without passing box as input

Comment: jsfiddle for a repro ?

Comment: you are moving the div after such a small duration , you can try by increasing the time and then try to click.

Comment: @Cétia, I added a stablitz code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example use `ngFor` structural directive and change reference to element in array. So angular destroyes and recreates the DOM every time you change reference.

[image]

This means you can't get click event working because you destroy element which listens click event.

There are different solutions which can prevent rebuilding DOM:

1) Use `ngForTrackBy` input

**html**

```
<ng-template ngFor ... [ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
```

**component**

```
trackByFn(i: number) {
   return i;
}
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/moving-div-b1mzxy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

2) Mutate object

```
boxes: any[]=[{ left: 0, top: 120}];
...

this.boxes[0].left = move++ % 700;
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/moving-div-uwxtls?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

[image]

Comment: I don't want to mutate the object, because I have to keep track of different objects in the array. For the seek of brevity, I have only one item in the array. Using `ngForTrackBy` is a great option here to keep track of the divs